# How to use list recursion in Rascal function definitions

Tags: rascal

How to write a recursive function over lists in Rascal?
I would expect something like the following to work, but it doesn't

```
list[int] inc([]) = [];
list[int] inc([int H, *int T]) = [H+1,inc(T)];
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to write it in this style, this will work:

```
list[int] inc([]) = [];
list[int] inc([int H, *int T]) = [H+1, *inc(T)];
```

Note the `*` in front of the recursive call to `inc`, this says to splice the results back into the list -- needed because `inc` returns a list itself. An alternative would be to write this second function as follows, which uses `+` for list concatentation:

```
list[int] inc([int H, *int T]) = (H+1) + inc(T);
```

A more standard way to write this in Rascal would be with a list comprehension, as:

```
list[int] inc(list[int] xs) = [ x + 1 | x <- xs ];
```

The `List` library also includes a function called `mapper` which allows you to map functions over lists; using that, you could write this as:

```
mapper(xs, int(int x) { return x + 1; });
```

where `xs` is a list of integers.